# type infered statically typed languages?

Tags: programming-languages, type-systems

are there any typeless typesafe languages? By typesafe I mean types are checked at compile time. By typeless I mean types are not declared.

I know this is easier than it sounds, maybe even impossible but for example if I had code like this

```
foo = {
   bar: 123;
}
```

In some imaginary language I can possibly know that `bar` is an `int` and foo is a struct/object/class with 1 int field.

Similarly if I do this

```
SomeFunc(v) {
  printInt(v.bar);
}
```

And elsewhere I do this

```
SomeFunc(foo);
```

All of that seems type checkable at compile time. With enough context it might even be type checkable across compilation units.

Are there any languages that have attempted this? Basically make it possible to rarely declare types and yet still be typesafe at compile time ?

Comment: declare everything `auto`;

Comment: Or use something that always does type inference.

Comment: https://www.haskell.org

Comment: A note on terminology: What you call a typesafe language is usually known as a language with a static type system. What you call typeless would correspond to inferred types, except that the latter implies a static type system while you seem to consider dynamically typed languages typeless too. In summary, you want a language that infers (or rather, *can infer*) all types.

Comment: You'll probably want to check out the ML family of languages (SML, OCaml, F#, Haskell to a slightly lesser extent). Most of them have very extensive type inference, so functions can be declared as `let myFunction x y = x + y` and it will figure out the types of `x` and `y` entirely from context. However, this sometimes means no function overloading. OCaml defines separate add functions for ints (+) and floats (+.)

Comment: @JensG You're using `Dynamic`, but this question is pretty clearly about static typing.

Comment: I should point out that there is at least one very good reason why you do not want this feature as much as you think you do: it can make compiler error messages an absolute pain to understand. The last time I did any work in a language that worked like this (an ML-like language called Miranda) I spent more time trying to understand compiler errors than I did writing code.

Comment: @Jules: The Scala community places an extremely high value on readable, understandable, helpful compiler error messages. So much so, that they actually refuse to add features to the language that would be very helpful, because they haven't yet figured out a way to implement them in such a way as to still provide good error messages. A more powerful type inference algorithm is one of those things: they have the math, they have the algorithm, they know how to implement in the compiler, they just don't know how to make it understandable where it goes wrong, when it does … so it's left out.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, pretty much everything in the Haskell/ML family does this. Here's a snippet of some relevant Haskell

```
 foo = 1 + bar
 bar = "Not a number :O"
 main = putStrLn foo
```

No types need to be explicitly annotated, but the error is still caught at compile time. In general we always infer some types in every language. Nothing would require something like

```
int bar = 1;
foo((bar : int) + (1 : int) : int) : string
```

Everyone supports at least inferring the types for subexpressions because otherwise the language is just unwritable. Usually the typechecker that the compiler runs will annotate the abstract syntax tree with these types. Only a few languages support global type inference, where we need write no types at all. There are some features which in general make complete type inference either difficult or impossible. An incomplete list

- Subtyping
- Polymorphism of rank 3 or higher
- Dependent types
- A completely monomorphic language (This is actually just ambiguous without some annotations)

PS I just wanted to make a note on terminology: type safe usually means that a well typed program always has defined behavior. Python is type safe and dynamically typed, C is not type safe and is statically typed.

I think what you want to say is a statically typed language that requires no type annotations :)

Comment: I'm fuzzy on this one: In what way is C not type safe by your definiton (always has defined behavior)? I thought C had defined behavior for pretty much everything in the type system (not necessarily GOOD behavior, just I though it was defined).

Comment: @MichaelKohne: The C language is *full* of undefined behavior.  For one rather egregious example specifically related to the type system, what does the following function prototype mean: `void foo(int* bar);`?  Is the parameter supposed to be an array of ints, or a pointer to a single int (because C doesn't support pass-by-reference so it has to be faked by using this idiom)?  And what happens if it's expecting an array but you pass it a pointer to a single int?

Comment: @MichaelKohne Anything undefined is what a PL theorist means by "goes wrong" or "gets stuck". In practice of course the program does *something*. It's just that what happens isn't predictable so it's bad. A well typed program in C can go wrong, so it isn't type safe.

Comment: @MichaelKohne In C you can hide whatever you want in a `void` pointer and cast it to anything else. I don't think you can do *worse* at being *not* typesafe than allowing basically *all* type conversions in such a way... Sure, you can restrict C to disallow some things (and I believe this is somewhat what was tried with Ada), but then it's not C, it's a different language with a different type system.

Comment: @bakuriu you can make whatever attempts you want to improve the type systems of languages with manual memory management, but they are all doomed to eventual failure because if you free an object and leave references to it behind, those can change into references to a different type of object at some arbitrary future time. Type safety and manual memory management are fundamentally incompatible.

Comment: @Jules Check out Rust. Its memory management is manual (in that one is in full control where stuff is allocated and when it's freed), but it prevents dangling references. There are of course escape hatches, but those exist even in Haskell and OCaml.

Comment: @Jules Actually that's not quite true, there's a fascinating type of type system called a *linear* type system which can ensure that each malloc matches one and only one free at compile time. Rust sports a version of such a type system

Comment: @Jules I don't think so... there are pretty complex theorem provers out there. You could define a language where you required explicit *formal proofs* of good memory allocation/deallocation in order to let the user use such functions. The compiler could verify the proofs. Surely, nobody would use such a language because you'd have to write tons and tons of lines of proofs for each tiny program bit, but it *would* be possible even with current technology and knowledge. However I don't think it will ever be feasible, since in writing the proofs you are basically rewriting the program itself.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Thanks. Interestingly, I've been doing C so long that I failed to see pointers as a breach of the type system. Walk the edge of a pit long enough and you forget how scary it is.

Comment: @jozefg - amusingly, I was recently reading a book about type systems, and it had a chapter on linear type systems.  This chapter, it turns out, was written by the lecturer who taught my class on programming language design when I was an undergraduate, and the book was published while I was studying that course. *facepalm*

Comment: @Jules which book was this?

Answer (score 6):

Type inference does exactly this. You do not generally have to declare types, as they can be inferred from usage. However, more complex type systems will still occasionally require explicit type annotations.

Your example can be written in Standard ML as

```
fun some_func {bar} = print (Int.toString bar);

val foo = {bar = 123};
some_func foo;
```

This uses pattern matching to obtain the `bar` field in the record passed to the `some_func`. The ML language pioneered type inference, but type inference is becoming a more common sight with various levels of support in Haskell, C++, C#, and Scala.

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far have mentioned extreme functional languages.  If you're looking for something a bit closer to the mainstream, have a look at Boo.  Its syntax is heavily inspired by Python, but it's statically typed.  Type declarations are required for defining class members, but for variables, method arguments and return types everything can be optionally given an explicit type, or type-inferenced if none is provided.

Comment: Is Boo still under active development? To be sure, it's going to be easier to pick up than ML or Haskell for someone coming from Python, but if it's a dead project...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: It's slow going at the moment, but there's currently an active effort under way to bring it up to a 1.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the least hard-core of the suggestions if FlowType (basically it is not a language, but a type annotation system for JavaScript). It is implemented using OCaml and has quite powerful type inference. I don't think a real task could be code based only on type inference, but in general FlowType can infer types for the most of cases.

You can play with it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoG2BGBDAJwC4YBGAJgGYAaDAXwG4MNRJYEQBRAgldLGPmIwA5BUoj6TDHACuYYFACW4GAGUQAWwCmAMXnAAFADcAlP2wBZPFAAWAOgIh5AExP2hppnWYad+hUMOLww-PQMgxG4CEKA).
[image]